# Code optimization for count of permutations starting x defined by DI sequence

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, optimization, permutation

I want to count all permutations which are in a certain subset defined by  `DI Sequence` and Matching given Start values.

Similar problem: `https://leetcode.com/articles/valid-permutations-for-di-sequence/`

example for permutation length 4:

We have the Input the Bitstring length 3 (always permutation length - 1)

`010`

`0` means `2` consecutive elements are `I`ncreasing.

`1` means `2` consecutive elements are `D`ecreasing.

For this Bitstring exist the subset with following permutations: `1324,1423,2314,2413,3412`

Now i want to count all permutations with the starting values `1,2`

Therefore i have this method call: `numsInDISequence(bitset, new int[]{1,1,0,0},4)`

Method:

```java
public int numsInDISequence(BitSet bits,  int[] start, int len){
    int[] dp =  Arrays.copyOf(start,start.length);
    int[] dp2 = new int[len-1];

    for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++){
        if(!bits.get(i)){
            for(int j=0; j<dp.length;j++){
                for(int k=j;k<dp2.length;k++) {
                   dp2[k]+=dp[j];
                }
             }
        }else{
             for(int j=0;j<dp.length;j++){
                for(int k=0;k<j;k++){
                    dp2[k]+=dp[j];
                 }
             }
         }
         dp = Arrays.copyOf(dp2,dp2.length);
         dp2 = new int[dp.length-1];
     }
     return dp[0];
}
```

This algorithm runs with `O(len^3)` is it possible to improve complexity to `O(len^2)` or better? If yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to make it happen within `O(len^2)` complexity. Just take the `O(N^2)` solution from linked similar problem and use the `start` array as initial `dp` array.

[similar problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-permutations-for-di-sequence/discuss/168278/C++JavaPython-DP-Solution-O(N2))